# Facebook app submission with empty list of permissions

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps

I'm trying to submit a request for a new Facebook app that just needs the *email*, *public_profile* and *user_friends* permissions, which are granted by default.
When filling the submission form you are forced to select one ore more permissions from the list on the left side of the form. Since I don't need any of them for my app, is there a way to skip this step and just submit a request with default permissions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don´t need to submit your App at all if you only want to use those 3 basic permissions. They are approved by default.

Comment: In my case, I couldn't enable the app because it did not have a contact email address. It said so on a tooltip when I hovered on top of the switch to enable the app. Took me a while to realize that was preventing me from doing it.